# grant_type vs response_type in OAuth2.0/OIDC

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, openid-connect

I can't quite understand the difference between **response_type** and **grant_type** in [OAuth2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-73)/[OIDC](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) specifications.

My guess is that **grant_type** is specified in the URL when interacting with a token endpoint (to get *access* and/or *refresh tokens*), and the **response_type** is used when interacting with the authorization end point to get the *identity token* and the *authorization code*. Is that right ?

If so, what should we use as a **grant_type** when using the *hybrid* flow?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**response_type** and **grant_type** are two mandatory parameters established in the OAuth 2.0 specification. OpenID Connect is built on OAuth 2.0, these two parameters are used in OpenID Connect too.

**response_type** is used against authorization endpoint. This parameter defines what authorization response must contain in its response. For example, `code` when using authorization code grant (similarly authorization code flow in OpenID Connect).

**grant_type** on the other hand is used against the token endpoint. It defines the **grant** used for the token request. For example, `authorization_code` is the grant used for the authorization code grant (similarly authorization code flow in OpenID Connect).

For hybrid flow, **response_type** is extended to have multiple segments. This was done through [OAuth 2.0 Multiple Response Type Encoding Practices](http://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-multiple-response-types-1_0.html). This enables you to use a response_type such as **`response_type=id_token%20token`**. And **grant_type** will be the same as if you used authorization code flow. It will be `code`. This is defined in the specification's [hybrid token request](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#HybridTokenRequest)